# R: item.diff.rasch(item) --> What format does the argument need

Tags: r

I am using the following R function for an IRT analysis:

```
item.diff.rasch(item)
```

As the manual says, `item` is a matrix containing information on item responses. I would like to generate this matrix  from a txt-file containing a table with test data.

My problem is that I don't know what format this table needs to have so that I can generate a matrix for the R function from it.

Comment: I believe it is from `psych` package. Note the the documentation is clear : `Under development. Not recommended for public consumption. See irt.fa and score.irt for far better options.`

Comment: Please make your question [fully reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) as it makes it much easier to answer.

Comment: Yes, it is from the psych package and as said in the comment by adstudy one can really not properly use the package. So I switched to the ltm package which seems to be a full implementation of the Item Response Theory. Does one of you have experience with the ltm package?

Answer (score 0):

Is your question is about how to get the data into `R`?  If you have your raw data in a `.txt` or `.csv` file, then you can read it in as follows:

```
mydata <- as.matrix(read.csv("myfile.txt"))
```

See `?read.csv` for various options, of which `header` might be the most relevant.  `read.csv` creates a data frame, and then `as.matrix` converts it to the matrix structure you want.  Another good thing to try is `str(some_object)` which will show you how an object is stored.  For instance, you can break the command above into two steps:

```
mydf <- read.csv("myfile.txt")
str(mydf)
mymat <- as.matrix(mydf)
str(mymat)
```

To see more clearly what `R` is doing.

Comment: That was already very helpful. Thank you. I have entered a table with the following format:
1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1
1 0 0 1
I executed the follwoing code:

library(psych)
mydata <- as.matrix(read.csv("item.txt"))
difficulty <- irt.item.diff.rasch(mydata)

And this error message:

Error in colMeans(items, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
Calls: irt.item.diff.rasch -> colMeans
Execution halted

How can I fix that? There is no non-numeric information in the table.

Comment: Even though it seems numeric, it may have been read in as character for some reason (did Excel touch it?), or integer (more likely), and the functions processing it didn't catch that.  `str(mydata)` should tell you how it was stored.  If character or integer, use `mydata <- as.numeric(mydata)` and then try it.  If that doesn't work, do `dput(head(mydata))` and paste what you get into your original question so we can troubleshoot.